# Missing \begin {document} error

Tags: pdftex

I'm really new to LaTeX so I apologize if this is a really basic question. I am trying to create tables from STATA (a statistical suite) using laTeX and have generated the following table code. However, I keep getting the Missing \begin{document} error whenever I try to render the table.

```
\begin{center}
\footnotesize
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{tabularx} {14cm} {@{} l Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y@{}} \\
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{9}{c}{\textbf{Patient died}} \\
\cmidrule(l{.75em}){2-10} 
\textbf{To died or exp. end} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{No}} &       
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Yes}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Total}} \\
\cmidrule(l{.75em}){2-4} \cmidrule(l{.75em}){5-7}\cmidrule(l{.75em})  
{8-10}
&No.&Col \%&Cum \%&No.&Col \%&Cum \%&No.&Col \%&Cum \% \\
\midrule
10 or less months&4&23.5&23.5&15&48.4&48.4&19&39.6&39.6 \\
11 to 20 months&6&35.3&58.8&8&25.8&74.2&14&29.2&68.8 \\
21 to 30 months&2&11.8&70.6&7&22.6&96.8&9&18.8&87.5 \\
31 or more months&5&29.4&100.0&1&3.2&100.0&6&12.5&100.0 \\
\textbf{Total}&17&100.0&&31&100.0&&48&100.0& \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace[.75ex]
\end{tabularx}
\par
\scriptsize{\emph{Source: }cancer.dta}
\normalsize
\end{center}
```

Comment: The code you have is no real document, it is just the code to create the table. You have to wrap this into a document class of your choice and a document environment and you have to provide the needed package imports.

Comment: welcome to tex.se! for compiling of this code you need complete `latex` document, beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: Maybe you are interested in this link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner

Answer (score 2):

this isn't a complete answer, but it might help.

your error message was `Missing \begin{document}`.
that means the error was caused by a package; latex never reached the body of the
document.

at the 2017 tug meeting, i presented a talk on debugging.  this error was touched
on briefly.  the [slides for the talk](http://www.gust.org.pl/bachotex/2017-pl/presentations/bbeeton-1-2017.pdf) are online; the relevant slides are
13 and 22, but the rest of the material might be useful as well, as it describes
how to dissect a log file.

briefly, what you need to do is find what `\usepackage` was involved to trigger
the error.  once you know that, you can construct a small test to make certain
that this is the culprit.  and then, if you're not experienced with latex,
come back here to ask for help.  (you can use the command `\listfiles` to show
the versions of packages involved; often such a problem is the result of a newer
version being required, but a helper will need to know what packages and what
versions were being used that triggered the error.)